# code inside a <script> tag not registering

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm trying to send an AJAX post request from my View to Controller to add new data into my database. But when I write a script to do so inside my View (Index.cshtml), it wouldn't work. I tried setting a breakpoint inside the function, and it says

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the
>   debugger's target code type is associated with this line. Possible
>   causes include: conditional compilation, compiler optimizations, or
>   the target architecture of this line is not supported by the current
>   debugger code type.

Disclaimer: it is possible that I'm doing this completely wrong, but I think I'm not, and I'm very confused why I'm getting this error. How can I do this properly?

The script I'm trying to run:

```
<script>
    $("#AddFriend").click(function () {
        mydata = { AddName: $("#AddName").val(), AddLastName: $("AddLastName").val(), AddAge: $("AddAge").val(), AddTag: $("AddTag").val() }
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/AddFriend",
            type: 'Post',
            data: mydata,
            success: null
        });
    });
</script>
```

The section of the code it refers to:

```
             <div>
                <label>Name:</label><input id="AddName" type="text" /> <br />
                <label>Last name:</label><input id="AddLastName" type="text" /> <br />
                <label>Age:</label><input id="AddAge" type="text" /> <br />
                <label>Tag:</label><input id="AddTag" type="text" /> <br />
                <label id="AddLabel"></label>
                <button id="AddFriend">Submit</button>
            </div>
```

The function inside the Controller the AJAX code should reach:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void AddFriend(string AddName, string AddLastName, string AddAge, string AddTag)
    {
        using (var context = new ContactEntities1())
        {
            Friend fr = new Friend();
            fr.userId = 1;
            fr.Name = AddName;
            fr.LastName = AddLastName;
            fr.Age = Convert.ToInt32(AddAge);
            fr.Tag = AddTag;
            context.Friend.Add(fr);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

(for the record, I'm setting the breakpoint at the following line:)

```
mydata = { AddName: $("#AddName").val(), AddLastName: $("AddLastName").val(), AddAge: $("AddAge").val(), AddTag: $("AddTag").val() }
```

Comment: have you checked break point after clicking AddFriend button?

Comment: This question isn't clear, I don't really know what you asking. It appears to be a cry for help more than anything. But without a clear question I can't see how this is answerable.

Comment: @Liam When I click the "AddFriend" button, nothing happens. Shouldn't the script execute at that point? And then when I added the breakpoint, I got the error message saying "the breakpoint will not currently be hit", which means it's not reaching that part of the code, and I have no idea why. That's my question

Comment: which script the js or the server side code? Have you debugged the javascript? Is the HTTP request happening? is the click firing?!

Comment: @RohitAgrawal When I click the button nothing happens, and the breakpoint stays the same - white circle with a red border (instead of a full red circle), and the error I posted above.

Comment: @Liam The js script is what I meant. And no, the click is not firing at all, I tried adding a line that changed a value of a label at the start of the click function, and it wouldn't execute either, so I think the click function itself is not executing

Comment: Javascript can be debugged (including setting breakpoints) by using your browser's developer tools, not with Visual Studio breakpoints. Your VS debugger is targeting C# not JS. That's what the warning message is telling you. You may be able to configure VS to debug JavaScript in the browser, but I'm not sure, you'd have to look it up. Easier just to use the browser tools I'd have thought. You can use them to look for errors as well which might indicate why the script is failing to execute.

Comment: One thing I note about your click-handling script is that isn't not wrapped in  a document.ready block. So if that script is included in your page _before_ the HTML it refers to, it won't work because it will try to bind the event to a HTML element which doesn't exist (the JS is executed at the moment it's rendered on the page, and the page is rendered in the order it's written, so if it's positioned before the target HTML in the file, then you'll get this problem). Wrapping in document.ready avoids this by telling the script to wait until the whole page has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

to answer the question

> the click is not firing at all, I tried adding a line that changed a
>   value of a label at the start of the click function, and it wouldn't
>   execute either, so I think the click function itself is not executing

I think your just missing a [`ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#AddFriend").click(function () {
        alert('click fired');
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <label>Name:</label><input id="AddName" type="text" /> <br />
      <label>Last name:</label><input id="AddLastName" type="text" /> <br />
      <label>Age:</label><input id="AddAge" type="text" /> <br />
      <label>Tag:</label><input id="AddTag" type="text" /> <br />
      <label id="AddLabel"></label>
      <button id="AddFriend">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

> The `.ready()` method offers a way to run JavaScript code as soon as
>   the page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate.